# How change the video tag poster attribute with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, native, poster

I want to use either native JavaScript or jQuery to change the poster attribute on the HTML video tag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="videoplayer" class="video-player" style="overflow: hidden; width: 582px; height: 326px; "> 
    <div id="myPlayer"> 
        <video id="htmlFive" width="100%" height="100%" controls="" poster="undefined">
            <source src="blank.m3u8">
        </video>
</div> 
     </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To do it natively, just change the attribute:

`document.getElementById('htmlFive').setAttribute('poster','newvalue');`

Answer (score 10):

Use jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method, e.g:

```
$('#htmlFive').attr('poster', 'newvalue')
```

Or native [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
document.querySelector('#htmlFive').setAttribute('poster', 'newvalue')
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect for jQuery, but now I am trying to do it natively.

Comment: Is there a way to re-set the poster when the video pause ?

Answer (score -4):

```
$('#video source').attr('src', srcPath);
```

Answer (score -5):

```
$("#example_video_1 .vjs-poster").css('background-image', 'url(http://video-   js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg)').show();
```

Comment: This sets a background image - not the video poster.